# Помогите FindViewById не видит id

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:xmls="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmls:cardElevation="4dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_image"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:background="@drawable/order_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Заказ"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#5f0e0d0e"
            android:id="@+id/menu_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```java
package com.curier.myapplication.ViewHolder;
    
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
import com.curier.myapplication.Interface.ItemClickListener;
    
public class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView txtMenuName;
    public ImageView imageView;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public MenuViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtMenuName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);
        imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_image);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    
    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.OnClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), false);
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]